# Ajax returns only first index of stringified array to the Spring controller

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring-mvc, stringify

Here's the whole JS code:

```
function getPoolsData(){
$.getJSON('../json/data.json', function(data) {

var date_from = new Date();
console.log(date_from);
var pools_hashrates = [{"date_from" : date_from}];

data.pools.forEach(function(pool){

var api_url = pool.api;
var poolName = pool.name;

if(pool.type == "forknote"){

    $.getJSON(api_url + 'stats', function(data) {

            var poolHashrate = data.pool.hashrate;

            pools_hashrates.push({"poolName" : poolName, "hashrate" : poolHashrate});

            console.log("Pool name: " + poolName + " Pool hashrate: " + parseInt(poolHashrate));
    });
}
else{
    $.getJSON(api_url + 'pool/stats', function(data) {

            var poolHashrate = data.pool_statistics.hashRate;

            console.log("Pool name: " + poolName + " Pool hashrate: " + parseInt(poolHashrate));

            pools_hashrates.push({"poolName" : poolName, "hashrate" : poolHashrate});

    });
}

});

console.log(pools_hashrates);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType : 'json',
  url: "/save",
  data: JSON.stringify(pools_hashrates),
  success :function(result) {
      console.log("Success!");
 }
});

});
}
```

Here's controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/save")
public @ResponseBody String getPoolsData(@RequestBody String string){

    System.out.println("Triggered: " + string);
    return "Success mvc";
}
```

And a controller output:

```
Triggered: [{"date_from":"2018-04-13T11:05:00.652Z"}]
```

The problem is, only the first index of an array is sent to the controller, while the array is about 20 in length. `console.log(pools_hashrates)` prints whole array. The script is invoked via button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax calls are async, which mean that it's going to fire all 3 of them up at once, the call to getPoolsData will not wait for the get to finish, you need to set the ajax calls to be async.

Like this

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
});
```

Note that this will set all ajax calls to be async, the better thing to do would be to rewrite your calls as such

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    type: "GET",
    data: ...,
    async: false
});
```

to make only those calls async

Or you could use setInterval to keep checking if jQuery.active == 0

```
jQuery.active == 0 // this tells you if you have active ajax calls
```

If would be something like this

```
var myTimer = setInterval((function(){ 
    if (jQuery.active == 0){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType : 'json',
            url: "/save",
            data: JSON.stringify(pools_hashrates),
            success :function(result) {
                console.log("Success!");
            }
        });
        clearInterval(myTimer); // stop the interval once you the get calls finished and you send the ajax call
    }
}, 1000)); // 1000 is the interval at which to check set in miliseconds
```

Comment: All 3 of them? There's only 1 ajax call? Sorry, I'm a java dev, so this is quite new to me.

Comment: $.getJson is just a shorthand for an ajax get call, you actually have and ajax call for each for loop, see here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Woah. So, do I need to set up an interval & `.active` flag on each specific ajax call?

Comment: jQuery.active just gives you the number of active ajax calls you have, so you need to do it only for the last one, since it's the only one that uses the data from the other

Comment: It worked, but I had to remove one pair of brackets starting right after `setInterval`. Thank you Sir :)